# I merged a pull request and GitHub automatically merged another one

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am experiencing an odd issue with GitHub and would like to know if it is by design. I merge a pull request and sometimes a separate pull request also gets merged. This seems to happen automatically. I've noticed, for the pull request that gets auto-merged by GitHub, its branch was merged into the branch of the pull request that I merged manually.

So, for example, I have branch `A`, which I am merging a PR for. I merge another branch, branch `B`, into branch `A` before merging the PR for branch `A`. I then merge the PR for branch `A`, and the PR for branch `B` is automatically merged.

**Is this by design?** It doesn't make any sense to me. Why would GitHub assume that branch `B` is ready to be merged into `dev` just because I merged it into branch `A`? In our team, we merge branches into each other to minimize conflicts when PRs are merged. I'd also like to know if it is possible to change this behavior somewhere in GitHub.

Comment: If you merge B into A, then A into master, why would you expect that B **wouldn't** be merged?

Comment: I think I get it. It's auto-merging pull request B because branch B is getting merged into dev anyhow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is by design: When you merge `B` to `A` you're saying `B` is now *fully part of `A`*. And when you then merge `A` to `dev` you're saying that `A` is fully part of `dev`. Transitively now `A` is part of `dev`, and `B` is part of `A`, therefore `B` is part of `dev`.

If you *don't* want `B` to be merged into `dev` when you merge `A` into `dev` you *must not* merge `B` into `A` (eg you *must not* tell git that `B` is part of `A`).

One thing that might be tripping you up: git is about the source, not the PR. Github is putting PR capabilities on top of what git is actually tracking. When Github sees that you've merged the code for a PR it closes the PR.

You state that `In our team, we merge branches into each other to minimize conflicts when PRs are merged.` and it sounds like you're actually doing this *backwards*. In your example typically what would be done is when `A` is merged into `dev` whoever owns `B` would merge from `dev` into `B`: thereby resolving any merge conflicts on `B` so when they merge `B` into `dev` the actual merge change *is just the changes required for feature `B`*, and there won't be any merge conflicts.