# Why does one merge request merge another?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

Start with an empty git repo in GitLab or BitBucket. Probably works the same in other git tools, I just haven't tried them.

(It works a little differently in BitBucket because it doesn't have the same feature set, but the fundamentals remain the same.)

Create 2 GitLab issues : "issue 1" and "issue 2".

Use the button on the issue to "Create an MR" in both issues (which will create branches)
(Leave the "Closes #" comment in the MR)

Edit "code" in issue-1 branch. Commit/push your change.

Now, start work on the issue-2 branch. "You rapidly realise this builds on issue1."
To get issue1's changes you can either merge or rebase on issue-1 branch. Merge/rebase both exhibit the same behaviour.

```
git merge issue-1 
git push
```

Now "someone important" calls and tells you issue1 "must be released NOW". So : Leave the CLI/IDE and in the browser, go to issue1 MR, "Mark as ready" persuade someone to approve it and merge it.

Now you've fixed issue 1, you want to finish work on issue 2. There is a branch ready for you and a Draft MR waiting. Right?? So you check your list of outstanding tickets and issue-2 is closed. "Yay someone else finished it for me while I was getting issue-1 released"

Check MR2 and issue2 and the issue2 branch :

- MR2 is merged (even though still Draft and not approved)
- issue2 is closed by merging branch issue-2

But now you get told off for not doing your ticket (which was closed and the MR for it was merged when you checked, so why would you do any more work?)

(If you had added another commit to issue 2 in this scenario, it wouldn't get merged.)

I found this because I'd done some work, someone else called me and asked for help, they needed what I had done. They merged my changes in and didn't get round to committing anything else. I was done with my work, so I got my MR approved and merged it. My colleague, who hadn't added anything beyond merging my changes into his branch then calls up : "Why are you closing my ticket when you did nothing? How the heck did you get that MR merged when it was still in Draft state and hadn't been approved??"

tl;dr **Isn't an MR an object with it's own state/lifecycle (that just happens to reference a commit)??**

If the commit is in the target branch or not that shouldn't change the MR's state, should it? The MR could have totally different comments, etc..

Is there a "better" way for my colleague to include my work and not have his ticket closed? (Other than doing more work before I get around to merging my changes, (possibly minutes) , or waiting (possibly days) for me to merge them, then rebase/merge from master).

(This is similar to : [I merged a pull request and GitHub automatically merged another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58884313/i-merged-a-pull-request-and-github-automatically-merged-another-one) But they create/merge branch B from branch A, I create/merge both mine from/to master.)

Comment: Did you merge with fast-forward or did the merge request create a new merge? The operations you list seems to start the history of the second feature with `git merge issue-1`, which I assume will do a fast-forward. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a "better" way for my colleague to include my work and not have his ticket closed?

If possible, they should rebase their own branch 'myBranch' on top of your `issue2` branch.
If they have created their own branch from branch `main` (or any other branch from which they started to work), they would do:

```sh
cd /path/to/repo
git fetch
git rebase --onto origin/issue2 $(git merge-base main myBranch) myBranch
git push --force
```

That will update their own MR. (Assuming they do communicate between their team the new branch history)